# THREE.js Mesh Vertices

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl

I am new THREE.js and making game in it. I want to ask that is there any command in THREE.js to find out the vertices where exactly the ray from a mesh hits to another mesh. Like if a ray emits from a car and hit the road so I want to find out the exact point where the ray ffrom the car hits the road.
I searched  for this a find out a command but it is not giving the solution

```
for(var i = 0; i < Mesh.geometry.vertices.length; i++){
 Mesh.geometry.vertices[k].x;
}
```

please help me in this regard.

Comment: btw you should make your question title more specific

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is - have a look at the [Raycaster](http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/docs/56/#Reference/Core/Raycaster) class which does exactly what you want.  The documentation is OK, but it's worth looking at the [source code](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/core/Raycaster.js) to see exactly what it does.

Here's an untested example:

```
var rc = new THREE.Raycaster(from, direction);
var results = rc.intersectObjects(your_scene_objects);
if (results[0])
  alert('hit at ' + results[0].point);
```

Comment: Is `Raycaster` Supported in r51 version of `THREE.js`?

Comment: Yes, but up to r54 it was called 'Ray'.

Comment: .. or to be more exact, the ray casting functions were bundled into the mathematical Ray object, where they didn't really belong. In r54 the functions were pulled out into their own object